# The encoding scheme is to subtract 2 from each character’s ASCII value

Tags: python, character-encoding, ascii

Basically I have a file that I need to decode.
I am new to coding and not really sure how to do this.

At the moment I have this code:

```
infile = open('encoded_2.txt')

for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    print(line,end=' ')
```

I'm getting this:

```
Ml rfc rp_gj rm Mpceml
```

But I'm expecting it to be:

```
On the trail to Oregon
```

Comment: The space character is also being encoded?

Answer (score 0):

One can use `ord` (to convert character to ascii number) and `chr` (to convert ascii number to character) functions:

```
line = "Ml rfc rp_gj rm Mpceml"
newline =""
for i in range(len(line)):
    newline += chr(ord(line[i])+2)
print(newline)
```

Output:

```
On"the"trail"to"Oregon
```

The space character is also being converted.

Apparently space is not encoded in original file. So one can exclude it from decoding:

```
line = "Ml rfc rp_gj rm Mpceml"
newline =""
for i in range(len(line)):
    if line[i] == ' ':
        newline += ' '
    else: 
        newline += chr(ord(line[i])+2)
print(newline)
```

Output:

```
On the trail to Oregon
```

The if condition can be put in one single line:

```
for i in range(len(line)):
    newline += ' ' if line[i] == ' ' else chr(ord(line[i])+2)
```

Comment: How do you get rid of the quotations tho, I don't need thoes.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> text = 'Ml rfc rp_gj rm Mpceml'
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(t)+2) if t != ' ' else t for t in text)
'On the trail to Oregon'
>>>
```